# CSS: Positioning of figcaption under image

Tags: html, css

I am using some styling to ensure images display with a given aspect ratio. It's working great, other than when using a `<figcaption>`.

The inspector shows the `<figcaption>` is positioned just below the image, but it doesn't display, most likely because of the `padding-bottom`.

How do I modify this to get the `<figcaption>` to display?

**EDIT:** I am trying to get the caption to display just under the image, not on top of it.

```css
figure, img {
  border-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.media-container {
  overflow: hidden;

}

.media-container > :first-child {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-'] {
  position: relative;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-']::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.aspect-ratio-21x9::before {
  padding-bottom: 42.86%;
}

.aspect-ratio-16x9::before {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.aspect-ratio-4x3::before {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}

.aspect-ratio-1x1::before {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-'] > :first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

figcaption {
  display: block;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<figure class="media-container aspect-ratio-16x9">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/500/500" alt="Photo"/>
  <figcaption>This is a 16x9 image with a caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position the `figcation` absolutely and make `overflow` visible on parent

```css
figure, img {
  border-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.media-container {
  overflow: visible;
}

.media-container > :first-child {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-'] {
  position: relative;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-']::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.aspect-ratio-21x9::before {
  padding-bottom: 42.86%;
}

.aspect-ratio-16x9::before {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.aspect-ratio-4x3::before {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}

.aspect-ratio-1x1::before {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-'] > :first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

figcaption {
  display: block;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  }
```

```html
<figure class="media-container aspect-ratio-16x9">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/500/500" alt="Photo"/>
  <figcaption>This is a 16x9 image with a caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I neglected to mention that I am trying to get the caption to display underneath the image, not on top of it. How would this be possible?

Comment: I've edited my snippet, I've positioned the caption absolutely and allowed the overflow to be visible on the parent

Answer (score 0):

The `figcaption` would need to be positioned absolutely.

This would also entail removing the `overflow:hidden` from the container.

**This may impact your overall design / page flow.**

```css
figure,
img {
  border-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.media-container {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  /* Removed*/
  width: 25%;
  /* for demo purposes */
}

.media-container> :first-child {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-'] {
  position: relative;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-']::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.aspect-ratio-21x9::before {
  padding-bottom: 42.86%;
}

.aspect-ratio-16x9::before {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.aspect-ratio-4x3::before {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}

.aspect-ratio-1x1::before {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-']> :first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

figcaption {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  color: red;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}


}
```

```html
<figure class="media-container aspect-ratio-16x9">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/500/500" alt="Photo" />
  <figcaption>This is a 16x9 image with a caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I neglected to mention that I am trying to get the caption to display underneath the image, not on top of it. How would this be possible?

Comment: You'd have to remove the `overflow:hidden` to do that...or rethink your design. Frankly, this is something more suited to a background image rather than an inline image

Answer (score 0):

I would add

```css
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

to `.figcaption`:

```css
figure, img {
  border-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.media-container {
  overflow: hidden;

}

.media-container > :first-child {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-'] {
  position: relative;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-']::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.aspect-ratio-21x9::before {
  padding-bottom: 42.86%;
}

.aspect-ratio-16x9::before {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.aspect-ratio-4x3::before {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}

.aspect-ratio-1x1::before {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

[class*='aspect-ratio-'] > :first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

figcaption {
  display: block;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure class="media-container aspect-ratio-16x9">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/500/500" alt="Photo"/>
  <figcaption>This is a 16x9 image with a caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```